# Pass Comma Separated String to IN clause in stored procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures

I am having comma seperated String and i am passing this comma seperated to oracle stored procedure. Now how to handle this string in cursor to IN clause.

```
String codes = "ABCD','EEFF','GGHH";
```

And cursor query is like

```
    CURSOR cur_bill_cod
   IS
      SELECT a.*
  FROM bill_codes a
 WHERE a.code in (p_codes)  ;
```

I declared p_codes as varchar in procedure.

But it is not fetching records.  I tried string passing in another way as

```
String codes = "ABCD,EEFF,GGHH";
```

But in both the ways it failing and it is not throwing any exception.
 Could you please help me out on this.

Comment: `String codes=" 'ABCD' ,'EEFF', 'GGHH' ";` Try Adding Single quotes correctly!

Comment: No it is not working

Comment: Had the same issue but I used a workaround in PL/SQL. Read: https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use:

```
CURSOR cur_bill_cod
   IS
      SELECT a.*
  FROM bill_codes a
 WHERE a.code in (  
            SELECT CAST (TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (p_codes,
                                '[^,]+',
                                1,
                                LEVEL)) AS VARCHAR2 (30))
                    codes
                FROM DUAL
            CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (p_codes, ',') + 1)
```

Comment: There is some thing wrong in your code, I am getting missing keyword error while compiling procedure. I also tried it as
 (SELECT CAST (TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (p_shipper_codes,'[^,]+',1,LEVEL)) ) from dual )  ;
but till it is giving same error

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the answer.